# I want to access a variable outside of setOnclicklistener and change its value. How can I do it?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to access these boolean variables and change them to true everytime I click each button. How am I able to do this?

```
class NewGame : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_game)
    val results = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView5)
    val results2 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView6)
    val greater = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button3)
    val equal = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button4)
    val less = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button5)
    val result = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView7)
    val submit = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button7)
    var great = false
    var equ = false
    var les = false
    var hasSubmitted = false



    greater.setOnClickListener {
        great = true
        equ = true
        les = true
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead,

Use onClick attribute in your xml like this,

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"    
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="buttonClicked" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"    
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="buttonClicked" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"    
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="buttonClicked" />
```

And create a function with the same name in your activity like this,

```
class NewGame : AppCompatActivity() {


    var great = false
    var equ = false
    var les = false
    var hasSubmitted = false

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_game)
    val results = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView5)
    val results2 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView6)
    val result = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView7)
   
 }

private fun buttonClicked(view: View) {
        great = true
        equ = true
        les = true
}
}
```

Click function will be triggered when any of the buttons clicked.

Note: don't forget to add this namespace in your xml header.

```
tools:context="yourpackage.NewGame"
```